# clang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead (Xcode 4)

Tags: xcode, llvm

I'm having this problem building a project using oauth in Xcode. It's a Mac App.

Do I have to patch llvm or something? I hope not...

Is there anywhere I can set this option in xcode?
Thanks!

Comment: I think [you can find the solution in this SO][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301649/xcode-4-clang-error

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to patch your source code so it does not use -I-, which has been deprecated for a long time. It's rather strange that an Xcode project is using that option, but sometimes build systems do strange things, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same error message. Apparently my mistake was to rename the source root folder (the one containing the xcodeproj bundle) to something containing a **space**! Once I renamed the folder to something without spaces, Xcode had no problem building the app.