# Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios5, exit-code

I am trying to integrate Facebook into my application. When copying the FBconnect file into my application and running it, my application shows the above error. If I remove FBconnet file, the application is fine without errors. What is the problem?

Error Displayed above that is:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/fExample2-Prefix-dgpfiszavygwrjgnbbtfhrwetzpp/fExample2-Prefix.pch.pth fExample2/fExample2-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/patrontechnosoft/Desktop/fExample2
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30200 -iquote /Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/Intermediates/fExample2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fExample2.build/fExample2-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/Intermediates/fExample2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fExample2.build/fExample2-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/Intermediates/fExample2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fExample2.build/fExample2-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/Intermediates/fExample2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fExample2.build/fExample2-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/patrontechnosoft/Desktop/New -IGMAT -I- -IPractice/facebook-iphone-sdk/src -I/Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/Intermediates/fExample2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fExample2.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/Intermediates/fExample2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fExample2.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -c /Users/patrontechnosoft/Desktop/fExample2/fExample2/fExample2-Prefix.pch -o /Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/fExample2-Prefix-dgpfiszavygwrjgnbbtfhrwetzpp/fExample2-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fExample2-hazidfxqkfibktcxoeovnngtzsxo/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/fExample2-Prefix-dgpfiszavygwrjgnbbtfhrwetzpp/fExample2-Prefix.pch.d
```

clang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: Without seeing the exact error message (displayed above that), and possibly the relevant code, no way to know.

Comment: You might want to upgrade to a newer version of Xcode. And a little more information wouldn't hurt...

Comment: @Mat @ Stephen Darlington Please check the error Now...

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301649/xcode-4-clang-error (found via a simple google search)

Comment: Still my application showing the Same Error